# Object reference not set to instance in preview mode for sc_translate

Tags: sxa, scriban

I am getting object reference not set to instance at **sc_translate** in preview mode

[image: Scriban error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object]

When i checked the scriban loc (10,57), it is **sc_translate**

What can be the possible reason for this?

Comment: At a guess, you have a code error in your BioScriban template on line 10, chr 57. Without more information on what your code looks like and what you have tried to resolve this so far, its hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: I have sc_translate at this location trying to fetch dictionary value. sc_translate able to give value in front end page and experience editor. 

This error is just coming in Preview mode.

Comment: @JagmeetKaur did you find any resolution to this one?

Comment: nope, havn't found yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are utilizing the shared site concept of **SXA**, please ensure that none of your **Site node** and **Site Dictionary Folder** are set to the "Never Publish" state. If they are, it may have an impact and lead to issues with the **"sc_translate"** functionality.

I encountered a similar issue in one of my projects, and this approach resolved it.